# jquery ui select menu does not scroll in android browser

Tags: android, css, jquery-ui, html, overflow

I am working on a mobile application that uses the [jquery UI select menu](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/).

It works great, but the problem is that I have a couple drop downs that are too long to fit.  When I look on my PC, the floating divs are scrollable - the desired behavior.  On the android device, however, the divs are not scrollable.

I'm not sure how to go about making them scroll on the mobile device.  I'm already using an [ios 4 scroll fix](http://pastebin.com/Vfm2cnHY).

Any ideas how to make the div scrollable on the mobile device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always used this script: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4 to support internal scrolling when the device doesn't support it. It could help you. Other solution would be to detect touch movement on that div, and, scroll the div programatically, depending on direction and speed of touch move. But you'd probably be better using iscroll-4, it's faster to use it and already has cross browser support.